# How can I sort products by category in Woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to make the default sort for products in my Woocommerce Shop page to be by category (eg: Rings, then Earrings, then Bracelets, etc.)
I added the following shortcode to the Shop page but nothing is happening.

`[product_category  orderby="ID"]`

Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You may use like this

```
[products limit="8" columns="4" category="rings"]

[products limit="8" columns="4" category="earrings"]
```

or

```
  [products limit="8" columns="4" category="rings,earrings"]
```